# ¿Como formular consulta SQL que vincule un valor string con un array?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Poseo los siguientes valores en dos tablas diferentes:

**VACANTES**

| id_vacante | nombre |
| --- | --- |
| 5449493a7b7cb31f028b4568 | Contador Público |
| 5506f9ea7b8cc343508b45e7 | Abogado |
| 1244f9ea7b1dd34350olff49 | Ingeniero |

**POSTULANTES**

| id_postulante | vacante | leads.vacante_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ff45gt8 | 5449493a7b7cb31f028b4568 | 5506f9ea7b8cc343508b45e7 |
|  |  | 1244f9ea7b1dd34350olff49 |
| gt67jl5 | 5506f9ea7b8cc343508b45e7 |  |

En donde se puede ver que leads.vacante_id es un ARRAY y solo posee valores cuando un postulante se postuló a más de una vacante. También quiero aclarar que el primer registro de "id_postulante" y "vacante" de la tabla POSTULANTES abarca las dos primeras filas como un solo registro (no pude hacer esto en el formato Markdown)

¿Cómo podría realizar una consulta, en la que aplicando JOIN pueda generar un conteo en una tabla final como la siguiente?

**TABLA FINAL**

| vacante | total_postulaciones |
| --- | --- |
| Contador Público | 1 |
| Abogado | 2 |
| Ingeniero | 1 |

Espero que se logre entender y desde ya muchísimas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

```
select nombre, count(*) as Total
from
(
 (
  select nombre, vacante 
  from vacantes v inner join postulantes p on v.id_vacante = p.vacante
 )
 union all
 (
  select nombre, leads.vacante_id as vacante   
  from vacantes v inner join postulantes p on v.id_vacante = p.leads.vacante_id
 )
) T
group by T.nombre;
```

Haces dos consultas internas:

```
select nombre, vacante 
from vacantes v inner join postulantes p on v.id_vacante = p.vacante
```

Y:

```
select nombre, leads.vacante_id as vacante   
from vacantes v inner join postulantes p on v.id_vacante = p.leads.vacante_id
```

La primera consulta relaciona las tablas por el **campo vacante** y la segunda consulta relaciona las tablas por el **campo leads.vacante_id**.

Estas dos consultas las unes utilizando el **operador de conjuntos union all**, posteriormente harías una consulta más general y es sobre esta consulta general que aplicas la **cláusula group by** obteniendo el total deseado.

Comment: Excelente! Re sirve, pero tengo una consulta. "leads.vacante_id" al pertenecer al array "leads" (no aclaré bien esto) no me permite manipularla facilmente. El programa me indica justamente este error, que no se puede utilizar en la consulta con el resto de valores STRING.

Answer (score -1):

Lo podrias hacer de esta forma:

```
SELECT nombre,count(vacante) from postulantes inner join vacantes on leads.vacante_id =  id_vacante group by nombre
```

recuerda que inner se usa para traer datos que existen en ambas tablas

agrupamos los datos por nombre para que nos agrupe la cuenta de cada postulacion por nombre

Puedes Consultar mas informacion de las joins aqui:
[Join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Comment: Hola! ¿Y esa consulta funcionaría considerando que la cantidad total de postulantes proviene tanto de postulantes.vacante como de postulantes.leads.vacante_id ? Me parece que no estaríamos considerando los dos valores que quedan en postulantes.vacante